# unable to run librdkafka=1.3.0 over docker

Tags: go, dockerfile, alpine-linux, librdkafka

I was trying to run librdkafka version 1.3.0 from alpine distribution over my docker container using this:

```
FROM golang:1.13.6-alpine3.10 as base

RUN apk add --no-cache --update librdkafka=1.3.0 librdkafka-dev=1.3.0 --update-cache --repository http://dl-3.alpinelinux.org/alpine/edge/community
```

but got this error while building image:

```
librdkafka-1.4.2-r0:
    breaks: world[librdkafka=1.3.0]
    satisfies: librdkafka-dev-1.4.2-r0[librdkafka=1.4.2-r0]
  librdkafka-dev-1.4.2-r0:
    breaks: world[librdkafka-dev=1.3.0]
```

Can someone tell me what might be possibly wrong here?

Comment: Are you specifically looking for `librdkafka:v1.3.0`? The `edge` repo you are trying to pull librdkafka from has `v1.4.2-r0` and `alpine:v3.11` has `librdkafka:v1.2.2-r0`

Comment: yes I am specifically looking for librdkafka:v1.3.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`librdkafka`](https://pkgs.alpinelinux.org/packages?name=librdkafka&branch=edge&arch=x86_64) package has been upgraded to 1.4.2.

In Alpine repositories, as opposed to Ubuntu for example, old package versions are not kept. This is mostly done for security reasons, AFAICT. When a package is upgraded, the old version is gone for good. This has the unfortunate side effect of breaking images that depend on specific package versions.

The currently available `librdkafka` 1.X versions on Alpine repositories are 1.4.2 (`edge`, `3.12`), 1.2.2 (`3.11)`, and 1.0.1 (`3.10`).

If you must use this exact version, you could try building it from [source](https://github.com/edenhill/librdkafka), using the [1.3.0](https://github.com/edenhill/librdkafka) tag.